# Primefaces imageSwitch width and height styles

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I'm having problems on resizing the images that my primefaces imageSwitch gets.
On the attached screenshot, you can see how I gave a red border with small size to the p:imageSwitch but the load images are outside.

[image]

**.xhtml p:imageSwitch:**

```
<p:imageSwitch styleClass="iSwitch" effect="fade" rendered="#{formBean.formBean1 eq null and formBean.formBean2 eq null}">              
    <ui:repeat value="#{imageSwitchBean.images}" var="image">  
        <p:graphicImage value="/img/#{image}" />  
    </ui:repeat>  
</p:imageSwitch>
```

**css styles:**

```
.iSwitch{
    border: solid red;
    width: 300px !important;
    height:150px !important;
}
```

**java Managed Bean:**

```
@ManagedBean
public class ImageSwitchBean {

private List<String> images;

public ImageSwitchBean() {
    images = new ArrayList<String>();
    images.add("img1.jpg");
    images.add("img2.jpg");
    images.add("img3.jpg");
    images.add("img4.jpg");
    images.add("img5.jpg");
    images.add("img6.jpg");
}

public List<String> getImages() {
    return images;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
.switcher {
    width: 600px !important;
    height: 380px !important;
}

.switcher img {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```